# Checking if all elements of list are same data type (atom I guess). Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am a total beginner in Prolog. I have some custom types: bird, animal and fish. I want to pass a list to a function like so `areSameType([owl, eagle, chicken])`. and get a result if the whole list is type bird or animal or fish. For example:

```
areSameType([owl,giraffe,shark]). > false
areSameType([owl,eagle,chicken]). > true
areSameType([cat,mouse,giraffe]). > true
```

The data I have inserted is:

```
bird(owl).
bird(eagle).
bird(chicken).
animal(cat).
animal(mouse).
animal(giraffe).
fish(shark).
fish(magikarp).
fish(gyarados).
```

I have tried with this function:

```
isSameType(X,Y):- bird(X),bird(Y);animal(X),animal(Y);fish(X),fish(Y).
areSameType([H1,H2|T]):- isSameType(H1,H2), areSameType([H2,T]).
```

But the problem is I don't have a criteria to check if H2 is the last element of the list or maybe I got it all wrong with this logic.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here with your `areSameType/1` predicate:

1. there is no stop condition: in case the list is empty, or contains exactly one element, than all the items in the list have the same type; and
2. you need to recurse with `[H2|T]` (notice the *pipe* `|`, instead of the comma `,`).

So we can fix this with:

```
areSameType([]).
areSameType([_]).
areSameType([H1,H2|T]):-
    isSameType(H1,H2),
    areSameType([H2|T]).
```

We can however use [**`maplist/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2) here, and write this predicate without recursion (well no recursion in the `areSameType/1` predicate itself), like:

```
areSameType([]).
areSameType([H1|T]) :-
    maplist(isSameType(H1), T).
```